# Не могу понять как работать с asterisk сервером

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip

Я установил [сервер](https://github.com/leedm777/homebrew-asterisk) на OS X и запустил его. Мне необходимо, чтобы 2 разных пользователя подключались к серверу и 1 мог позвонить другому. Могу ли я обойтись для этих целей обойтись ARI?

Answer (score 1):

ARI нужно для управления asterisk-ом из сторонних приложений (на различных ЯП). Если Вам нужно просто совершить звонок между двумя пользователями, настраиваете в sip.conf два пира:

```
[user1] 
type=friend
username=user1
secret=user1
host=dynamic
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
context=test

[user2] 
type=friend
username=user2
secret=user2
host=dynamic
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
context=test
```

В extensions.conf прописываете диалплан:

```
[test]
exten => user1,1,Dial(SIP/user1);
exten => user2,1,Dial(SIP/user2);
```

Выполняете `sip reload` и `core reload`, чтобы прочитались конфиги. Клиенты с софтфонов конектятся на ip сервера с asterisk на порт 5060 (по умолчанию для SIP, можно изменить в sip.conf). Логины и пароли для них user1/user1 и user2/user2. По идее этого должно быть достаточно для простейшего звонка.

Comment: Забыл упомянуть, что мне нужно именно на ЯП (Objective C/Swift и Java)

Comment: Кто инициатор звонка? Стороннее приложение, которое хочет соединить двух абонентов или один звонит, потом вызывается приложение, которое дозванивается до второго?

Comment: По идее в одном приложении должно быть видно других абонентов, подключенных к серверу. Пользователь звонит через приложение подключенному абоненту и этот абонент в таком же приложении принимает звонок

Comment: У asterisk есть на данный момент три интерфейса для взаимодействия со сторонними приложениями: AMI, AGI, ARI. Вызов AGI-скриптов применяется, когда логика обработки звонка достаточно сложна в описании на языке конфигурации дилаплана, либо когда какие-то возможности недоступны вовсе. AMI позволяет инициировать звонки со стороны, отслеживает всевозможные события. ARI - смесь AGI и AMI.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, Вам нужно приложение-обертка для SIP-клиента. Звонок соответственно посредством SIP осуществляется. Список абонентов, инициализация звонка с помощью ARI

Comment: Да, все именно так.

Если в контексте ARI - 1 абонент это 1 channel? Дозваниваться должны до channel?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52387/discussion-between-carapuz-and-gikas).